# Python operator overloading with multiple operands

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-2.x

I know I can do simple operator overloading in python by the following way.

Let say overloading '+' operator.

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self,value):
    self.value = value

  def __add__(self,other):
    return self.value + other.value

a1 = A(10)
a2 = A(20)
print a1 + a2
```

But It fails when I try to do the following,

```
a1 = A(10)
a2 = A(20)
a3 = A(30)
print a1 + a2 + a3
```

Since the `__add__` accepts only 2 parameters. What is the best solution to achieve operator overloading with n number of operands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is failing because `a1 + a2` return an `int` instance and its `__add__` is called which doesn't support addition with the custom class `A`; you could return a `A` instance in `__add__` to eliminate the Exception for this specific operation:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self,value):
    self.value = value

  def __add__(self,other):
    return type(self)(self.value + other.value)
```

Adding them together now behaves in the expected way:

```
>>> a1 = A(10)
>>> a2 = A(20)
>>> a3 = A(30)
>>> print(a1 + a2 + a3)
<__main__.A object at 0x7f2acd7d25c0>
>>> print((a1 + a2 + a3).value)
60
```

This class of course suffers from the same issues with other operations; you need to implement the other dunders to return an instance of your class or else you'll bump into the same result with other operations.

If you want a nice result displayed when you `print` these objects, you should also implement `__str__` to return the value when called:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self,other):
        return A(self.value + other.value)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.value)
```

Now printing has the effect you need:

```
>>> print(a1 + a2 + a3)
60
```

Comment: Why _temporarily_? Looks like the proper solution to me.

Comment: temporarily might be a wrong word, point is this fixes the issue for the specific operation but in general you'll get weird results if you don't implement all required operations.

Comment: Thanks.But I wanted to have the result by just giving a1 + a2 + a3 ,not using the value attribute externally.

Comment: Then you overload `__str__` (and maybe `__repr__`) @karthi_ms to return the result :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

`a1 + a2 + a3`
gives
`30 + a3`

30 is an int, and ints do not know how to sum to A

You should return an instance of A in your `__add__` function